# Inner Join Results from two separate queries

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-order-by, inner-join, aginity

I have to query results from three different tables and so far have been able to get the separate results individually. Now I'd like to join these results. The following two pieces of code are my queries. Should I nest the two somehow? I would want to inner join on the s.STORE_NUM and str.num from the bottom query, how would I declare the two separately though?

```
SELECT
S.STORE_NUM,
M.YEAR_FISCAL,
--M.YEAR_445,
M.MONTH_NAME_445,
M.WEEK_START_DT_MON,
SUM(SALES_NET) - SUM(S.SALES_GCARD_NET) as SALES_WT_GC,
SUM(S.TRAFFIC_COUNT) AS TRAFFIC,
SUM(S.TICKETS_NET) AS  TRANS,
SUM(S.QTY_NET) AS UNITS,
-- Calculation level:
SUM(S.QTY_NET)/SUM(S.TRAFFIC_COUNT) AS UOT,
SUM(S.QTY_NET)/SUM(S.TICKETS_NET) AS UPT,
SUM(S.TICKETS_NET)/SUM(S.TRAFFIC_COUNT) AS CONVPCT
FROM DNA_PUBLIC..RETAIL_SALES_BY_STORE_BY_DAY S
JOIN DNA_PUBLIC.ADMIN.DAY_MAP M
ON S.DATE_DATA = M.DATE_DT
WHERE  S.DATE_DATA BETWEEN '08/24/2020' AND '09/27/2020'
AND S.SALES_NET > 0
AND S.TRAFFIC_COUNT > 0
AND S.QTY_NET > 0
AND S.TICKETS_NET > 0
AND S.STORE_NUM = 2Ah 
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
ORDER BY S.STORE_NUM, WEEK_START_DT_MON
```

and

```
SELECT r.str_num, r.str_nam, r.str_dst, s.region_name, s.div_name, r.STR_ADDR, r.str_cty, r.str_zip5 
FROM admin.retail_store_names r JOIN admin.store_dim s ON r.str_num = s.store_num
```

Comment: Correct, I took out the join and order by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would want to inner join on the s.STORE_NUM and str.num from the bottom query, how would I declare the two separately though?

You can join both resultsets by turning the queries to subqueries, and joining in the outer query. The `order by` clause goes to the outer query:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (
    -- first query goes here (without the "order by")
) t1
inner join (
    -- second query goes there
) t2 on t2.str_num = t1.store_num
order by t1.str_num, t2.week_start_dt_mon
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do -

```
            SELECT
            S.STORE_NUM,
            M.YEAR_FISCAL,
            --M.YEAR_445,
            M.MONTH_NAME_445,
            M.WEEK_START_DT_MON,
            max(r.str_num) As str_num,
            max(r.str_nam) As str_nam,
            max(r.str_dst) As str_dst,
            max(st.region_name) As region_name,
            max(st.div_name) As div_name,
            max(r.STR_ADDR) As STR_ADDR,
            max(r.str_cty) As str_cty,
            max(r.str_zip5) As str_zip5,
            SUM(SALES_NET) - SUM(S.SALES_GCARD_NET) as SALES_WT_GC,
            SUM(S.TRAFFIC_COUNT) AS TRAFFIC,
            SUM(S.TICKETS_NET) AS  TRANS,
            SUM(S.QTY_NET) AS UNITS,
            -- Calculation level:
            SUM(S.QTY_NET)/SUM(S.TRAFFIC_COUNT) AS UOT,
            SUM(S.QTY_NET)/SUM(S.TICKETS_NET) AS UPT,
            SUM(S.TICKETS_NET)/SUM(S.TRAFFIC_COUNT) AS CONVPCT
            FROM DNA_PUBLIC.RETAIL_SALES_BY_STORE_BY_DAY S
            JOIN DNA_PUBLIC.ADMIN.DAY_MAP M
            ON S.DATE_DATA = M.DATE_DT
            JOIN admin.retail_store_names r
            ON S.Store_num = r.Str_num
            JOIN admin.store_dim st
            ON r.str_num = s.store_num
            WHERE  S.DATE_DATA BETWEEN '08/24/2020' AND '09/27/2020'
            AND S.SALES_NET > 0
            AND S.TRAFFIC_COUNT > 0
            AND S.QTY_NET > 0
            AND S.TICKETS_NET > 0
            AND S.STORE_NUM = 2Ah 
            GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
            ORDER BY S.STORE_NUM, M.WEEK_START_DT_MON
```